# Javascript function stored in variable error

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason why I would be getting the error

Uncaught TypeError: inter is not a function
at movingPiece (script.js:270)
at keyboardMove (script.js:146)

in this code:

```
var inter = setInterval(function() {
  draw();
  b_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
  b_ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  b_ctx.beginPath();
  b_ctx.arc(xcoord, y, 45, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  b_ctx.fill();
  y += 1;
  if (y > endY) clearInterval(inter)
}, 25);

inter();
```

Comment: `setInterval` does not return a function?! Just drop the `inter();` statement and your code should work. Why did you think did you need it, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: It is basically an animation where a circle drops vertically. I wasn't sure if I needed to call inter() at the end

Comment: I am guessing he wants it called at a later period.

Answer (score 1):

inter is not really a function. So you can't call it. It is called automatically every 25 millisecond.

You are getting the error because you are calling it. It is automatically called. You don't need to call it or invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` does not return a function. Modify it like this.

```
   var inter = function(){
                    var interVar = setInterval(function(){
                    draw();
                    b_ctx.globalCompositeOperation="copy";
                    b_ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
                    b_ctx.beginPath();
                    b_ctx.arc(xcoord, y, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                    b_ctx.fill();
                    y+=1;
                    if(y>endY) clearInterval(interVar)}, 25);
               }
```

Then you can run `inter()` and have it run `setInterval`

Comment: Hi I've been using this code but for some reason, the y variable doesn't increment. I've set the variable to y=55 before your code and it just stays at 55

Comment: The console doesn't print any errors either. I put an alert("boom") before the if statement and it doesn't execute. It just carries on to the end and goes back to the calling function

Comment: Pass the y variable as a function parameter and call inter(y)? Might be a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inter = function(){
  var x= setInterval(function(){
                draw();
                b_ctx.globalCompositeOperation="copy";
                b_ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
                b_ctx.beginPath();
                b_ctx.arc(xcoord, y, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                b_ctx.fill();
                y+=1;
                if(y>endY) clearInterval(x)}, 25);
}
inter();
```

Comment: That will throw an error as you cannot run `clearInterval` on `inter` which is the container function now.